# How do we target elements that start with a false *ngIf condition?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I need to effect the attributes and or styles of dom elements that aren't present until an `*ngIf` condition returns true which I'm attempting to access with a `@viewChild()` decorator.  So far no matter what I attempt to do I'm getting an error saying

> Cannot read property nativeElement of undefined

I came across a few resources saying we should apply `ChangeDetectorRef` so we can update the component manually after setting the variable that toggles the dom element however I haven't had any luck with this method either.The examples I've come across don't even use `{static: true}` in their `@viewChild()` decorators so I figured maybe there were other changes made under the hood that requires modifying how we need to go about applying this solution, or maybe there's a different encouraged standard now all together.

My code currently looks like this:

***inside component***

```
//Where my data enter the component.
@Input() ElementData : OvaadGraphicObject;

TemplateType: string; //this variable toggles the *ngIf conditions
@ViewChild('graphicContainer', {static: true}) GraphicContainer: ElementRef;


//setting the TemplateType variable when the component initializes
ngOnInit(): void{ this.TemplateType = this.determineElementType(); }

//attempts to effect dom element after *ngIf condition is true and element exists
ngAfterViewInit(): void{ this.initGraphic(); }


/*I was initially setting the TemplateType var here and decided to split it apart to
  set things in different lifecycles to force it to work in the proper order.*/
private initGraphic():void{
    if(this.ElementData.selfClosing){
      this.ForgedElement = this.buildElement();
      this.TemplateType = 'single element';
    }
    else{
      //this.TemplateType = this.determineElementType();
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();//

      /*this checks to make sure the var isn't undefined before attempting to access the dom element
        which from the console.log provides the correct result*/
      if(this.TemplateType !== undefined){
          console.log(this.TemplateType);
          this.applyElementProperties();//this is what attempts to modify the dom element
      }
      else{ console.log('GRRRRRRRR!!!!!!!'); }

    }
  }

private applyElementProperties():void{
    const attributes: OvaadGraphicAttribute[] = this.ElementData.attributes;
    const styles: OvaadSvgStyleProperty[] = this.ElementData.styles;

    if(attributes.length > 0){
        attributes.forEach(a=>{

            //GraphicContainer is somehow still undefined at this point causing an error
            this.GraphicContainer.nativeElement.setAttribute(a.attribute, a.setting);
        });
    }
    if(styles.length > 0){
        styles.forEach(a=>{
            this.GraphicContainer.nativeElement.style[a.property] = a.setting;
        });
    }
  }
```

***inside my template***

```
<svg:g *ngIf="TemplateType === 'single element'" [innerHtml]='insertElement()'></svg:g>

<svg:g #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType == 'group element'">

    <svg:g svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg:g>

</svg:g>

<svg:linearGradient #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType === 'linear gradient'">

    <svg:g svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg:g>

</svg:linearGradient>

<svg:radialGradient #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType === 'radial gradient'">

    <svg:g svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg:g>

</svg:radialGradient>

<svg:symbol #graphicContainer *ngIf="TemplateType === 'linear gradient'">

    <svg:g svg-component *ngFor="let item of ElementData.subElements" [ElementData]="item"></svg:g>

</svg:symbol>
```

As you see in my template I'm using `#graphicContainer` on every item except minus the first item.  I figured that due to how `*ngIf` works there wouldn't be any confusion in the dom because there will always only be one of them rendered.  I deleted the `#graphicContainer` from all but one just to see if they were causing some type of confusion but the behavior stayed the same.  How can I get this to work?

***Update***

To help understand more of what's happening this is what the `determineElementType()` function looks like.

```
private determineElementType():string{
    const item: string = this.ElementData.element;
    let elementType: string;

    if(item === 'g'){ elementType = 'group element'; }
    else if(item === 'linearGradient'){ elementType = 'linear gradient'; }
    else if(item === 'radialGradient'){ elementType = 'radial gradient'; }
    else if(item === 'symbol'){ elementType = 'symbol'; }
    else{ elementType = 'unknown element'; }

    return elementType as string;
  }
```

I could set the `*ngIf` condition to work directly off the main data abject which comes through an `@Input()` but this functionality won't be needed in every instance of use.  In the instances that it does, other things need to be done before toggling the element otherwise other errors can occur from other things not existing to in turn render into the element, so that's why I'm doing it this way instead of just using `*ngIf="ElementData.element === 'g'"` for example.

Comment: It seems that `GraphicContainer` isn't `static`. Try to remove `{static: true}` and check it.

Comment: is `determineElementType` do anything related to dom or it just set the data and is it async operation ??

Comment: I just updated my post with the `determineElementType()` function.

Comment: when I delete the `{static:true}` part I get this error `Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.`.

Answer (score 0):

`TemplateType` must be initialized in ngOnInit then you can get reference of the dom elements , don't try to change the states of any element at ngAfterViewInit method and you dont need to call `this.changeDetector.detectChanges();`

```js
ngOnInit(): void{ 
 this.TemplateType = this.determineElementType(); 
 if(this.ElementData.selfClosing){
      this.ForgedElement = this.buildElement();
      this.TemplateType = 'single element';
  }
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void{ this.initGraphic(); }

private initGraphic():void{
    if(!this.ElementData.selfClosing && this.TemplateType !== undefined){
          console.log(this.TemplateType);
          this.applyElementProperties();
     }else{ console.log('GRRRRRRRR!!!!!!!'); }    
 }
```

Comment: how `ElementData` get set

Comment: through an `@Input()`, which I can bind the data directly into the template without a problem so it doesn't seem to be an asynchronous issue with the data, in fact I don't even think I'd be able to get far enough to have this current problem if it were that lol.

Comment: check this demo I have made https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hngfw9

Comment: if you change the selfClosing then you will get `GRRRRRRRR`

Comment: in that demo you're taking out everything in the `applyElementProperties()` function.  I can `console.log()` my results and get the correct results, it's the code inside the `applyElementProperties()` function that throws the error saying `cannot read nativeElement of undefined`. I'm trying to add attributes and styles to the dom element retrieved by the `@viewChild()` decorator.

Comment: if it possible just create a demo on stackblitz or github then I can check it , so I can he lp